# Fancybox - Setting the parent window's global variable from within a child fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

Here is the issue at hand:

The overall development is being done using Ruby on rails; however, the views consist of mostly html and jQuery. Currently, I have it set up so that when a user types into a text field, they can press a small "suggest" button beneath it which opens up a Fancybox where there is a list of useful Search terms, provided by the Google Suggest API. This is all set up and working. Now I want to take this to the next step, where, from inside of the Fancybox, the users can click on one of the suggestions and it will replace the initially typed in phrase in the parent window. Sadly I am not adept at using AJAX yet so I am trying to do this via javascript. This is what I have thus far:

In the parent window:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var $_returnvalue = false;
       $('.suggest_link').fancybox({
          onClosed: function(){
          alert($_returnvalue);
          if ($_returnvalue != false)
          {
            // I will be setting the textbox value here.
          }
       }
    });
</script>
```

In the partial view rendered inside of the fancybox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $_fancyvalue = false;
     $(".suggestion").click(function(){
        alert(parent.$_returnvalue);
        parent.$_returnvalue = $(this).text();
        $.fancybox.close();
     });
});
</script>
```

Sorry if there is anything strange with this post. This is my first time asking a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `var $_returnvalue` in the global scope in the parent window. Try this it will work fine.

```
var $_returnvalue = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.suggest_link').fancybox({
          onClosed: function(){
          alert($_returnvalue);
          if ($_returnvalue != false)
          {
            // I will be setting the textbox value here.
          }
       }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess that putting it inside of the Document ready function made it only stick inside of that scope.